# How to get User.Identity working outside controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have separate project with some of my custom ASP.NET MVC helpers

In one of my helpers I need to check user identity.

How may I get `User.Identity` working there?

By default it is living in `System.Security.Principal` in interface called `interface IPrincipal`

Comment: I see you haven't upvoted any answer yet. I suggest you to do so in the spirit of the site. Choose answers as right, too. That is the best way to thank the people that help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The HtmlHelper has the current ViewContext and via HttpContext you'll get the User object for the current User. In your extension Method you can use this

```
public static bool MyHelper(HtmlHelper helper)
{
    var userIdentity = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;
    // more code
}
```

Comment: Zokas answer below is better

Answer (score 56):

More easily you may access it by:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

So the HttpContext.Current is the trick.

Comment: this is the better answer

Comment: That's the best answer

Comment: Does this require any nuget packages? I am using IOC to inject services into my controllers, and I'm not able to retrieve user information outside of my API.

Comment: @erbaker Do you have a `using System.Web;` at the top of the file?

Comment: If you cant get this to compile, try HttpContext.User.Identity.Name