# How to get Authentication Claims outside controller in c sharp?

Tags: c#, api, httpcontext, claims

In my controller, I can access authenticated user details using the User property:

```
var currentUserClaims = User.Claims;
```

I have another project in my solution that needs to check the user claims. I have tried to use this solution that I got from the following link - [How to get User.Identity working outside controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898170/how-to-get-user-identity-working-outside-controller):

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

But it says that HttpContext does not exist in the current context. It suggests to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstraction. When I do this, it says Current is not part of HttpContext.

Any hint of how I can retrieve user claims outside the controller in another project please?

Answer (score 2):

With that package  installed you register `IHttpContextAccessor` in DI:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

And then you inject that in wherever you need it

```
public class MyClassWhichNeedsHttpContext
{
    public readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;
    public MyClassWhichNeedsHttpContext(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public void MethodWhichUsesIt()
    {
         var httpContext = accessor.HttpContext;
         var user = httpContext.User;
    }
}
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 2):

Try using IHttpContextAccessor. try to get this interface in constructor as a dependency. and then you should be able to access the context. Example:

```
internal class Example : IExample
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public Example(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        var claims = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims;

        ...
    }
}
```